# RMI Server Application doesn't keep on running (silently terminates)

Tags: java, garbage-collection, server, rmi

I have followed a bunch of tutorials on this RMI business to learn about how to do it right. Oracle's tutorial makes use of a `SecurityManager`, while most others don't bother. Some extend the `UnicastRemoteObject`, while others `exportObject`. Some run the `RMIRegistry` from outside and `getRegistry`, while others `createRegistry`.

Now, I thought that it would be beneficial for me to cherry pick out of those options in front of me, so here's what I've done:

First, I have gone for the security, because why not?

Second, I did not prefer extending the `UnicastRemoteObject`, because my object is not altogether remote, just has some remote methods. It just didn't seem right to me to have a `throws RemoteException` clause at its constructor, for example.

And lastly, I did not want to run the registry from outside, because I am not really running a server, it is just an application. Besides, I did not want to have two/three separate places to set the *port* for the registry.

Here's my code for the server alone, (hopefully) doing things I've described:

```
package server;

import interf.TicTacToeBoard;

import java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class TicTacToeServer
{
    private static Registry registry;

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException
    {
        System.out.println("Server is up!");

        System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "file:/<policy_file_path>");

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());

        TicTacToeBoardImpl arena = new TicTacToeBoardImpl();
        TicTacToeBoard stub =
            (TicTacToeBoard) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(arena, 0);

        registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(TicTacToeBoard.RMI_PORT);
        registry.bind(TicTacToeBoard.RMI_NAME, stub);

        System.out.println("Waiting for connections.");
    }
}
```

This thing isn't complete; but in terms of being capable of serving a remote object, it should be. However, after printing that line with `"Waiting for connections."`, the application just silently terminates.

My only explanation to this is that the application gets garbage collected.

It wouldn't get garbage collected in Oracle's example, because there, the RMIRegistry runs as a separate application from the server application, and RMIRegistry app holds a reference to the object residing inside the server app.

It doesn't get garbage collected when my implementation `extends UnicastRemoteObject`, because... I don't know. All I know is that the application then keeps on running.

Please correct me, if I have been wrong at any stage. On top of that, my question is, what are my options which does not involve running a RMIRegistry as a separate process and making my implementation extend the `UnicastRemoteObject`?

Comment: Um, your main method returns, so your process ends?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. @bmargulies No.

Comment: I'm suffering from exactly the same problem. I really need to fix this before a deadline.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen.<sup>1</sup> The existence of two remote objects should keep the port listening thread running, and the static variable should keep the registry object in existence. Try making the implementation and the stub static fields, like the registry.

> I have gone for the security, because why not?

But why? It's just a pain in the neck unless you're going to be running untrusted code, or in somebody else's computer.

1: Indeed it doesn't happen to me. It keeps running. Are you sure your `Registry` reference is really `static`?

Comment: Unless you are meaning something else than the `static` declaration behind the `registry` field, yes, I am sure. The code I have is just what I have posted, except, of course, the policy file path is really the policy file path. And, since I am able to call `exportObject`, I also am sure that my objects implement, directly or indirectly, the `Remote` interface.

Comment: I am trying to do this directly on Eclipse Luna, if that matters.

Comment: I tried it with a local `Registry` field instead of a static field. It took an hour to exit, because of the DGC lease interval. Are you sure no exception was thrown?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I am also sure that it rather properly serves when I append that code with a `while (true) Thread.yield();`, which is what I currently have. I don't take that `yield` as a solution though, just a workaround.

Comment: That's extremely wasteful. Instead of `yield()` use `sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`. It shouldn't be necessary, but the RMIRegistry does it.

Answer (score -1):

In m case this happened when I forgot the ...`extends UnicastRemoteObject` in my class definition.

Comment: In which case you no doubt removed `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(arena, 0).`  But it's not a question of 'forgot', unless you didn't have the line above in the first place, in which case you weren't dealing with a remote object at all. Not extending `UnicastRemoteObject` is a perfectly valid choice on its own.